# Turn off caching of web service response

Tags: php, web-services

I crete a web service in php and which returns JSON. It works fine but it seems to be cache results I changed values in the table and the service doesn't reflect this change. I included the following code but it doesn't seem to work. in my browser I am still getting the old values. How can this be rectified?

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
```

Comment: How is your HTTP request?

Comment: its a get request as I say the requests and service works fine just when I update the content the webservices don't update also

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your Ajax library (client) documentation see if you can disable its caching mechanism.

If you wish to disable cache on server side, refer to "[How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers)"

Comment: I have tried these methods and they still don't work if I do a direct query on the database it works but not the web-service